# Force to capture video in Landscape

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-orientation, android-camera-intent

I am trying to insist user to use **Landscape** mode while capturing video.

```
Question 1: Can I force user to use landscape mode while video capturing?
Question 2: Can I show some overlay image or alert to suggest the user for landscape mode when user holds device in portrait mode?
```

I tried to achieve it by using **default Camera App** with following piece of code,

```
Intent mOptionIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
mOptionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(mOptionIntent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_VIDEO);
```

I found that we can request for orientation of output data by specifying [EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION) as shown below.It can work on some devices only if `OEMs` have not modified, And even if it happens, the Camera might be open in `Portrait` and save data with `Landscape orientation`, so there is no way to set `Landscape` camera:

```
mOptionIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

So my concern is about orientation while Video capturing, I want to `insist user or lock the screen in Landscape mode`.

Answer (score 5):

I've created a library called LandscapeVideoCapture which does exactly that.

In portrait you will get an image indicating that the user should rotate his device and only when the device is in landscape, the user can actually start capturing a video.

Check it out here: https://github.com/jmolsmobile/LandscapeVideoCapture

Further this library has many other features such setting resolution, framerate, capture quality,...

Comment: Thanks for your time but I wanted to achieve it using `Default Camera App`. So that user can take advantage of all the features including different scene modes etc.

Comment: For what it is worth, I've updated my library to make it more flexible and accessible via Maven. Maybe it suits your needs now?

Comment: Awesome library @jmols